# How to start mysqld and then run query immediately from command line?

Tags: mysql, docker

I'm trying to run a "one off" mysql query on a mysql docker container which is not running.

```
docker-compose \
  run --rm db \
  mysqld & mysql my-db-name -e "SELECT *"
```

this doesn't really work because it's not waiting for mysqld to be started.

Comment: I edited your title - you don't really want it to happen without mysqld running (clearly that would be impossible). I think you are really asking how to start mysqld, know it's started, and then be able to run the query?

Comment: maybe a utility exists that works without mysqld running, I dont know

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's not really any shortcuts here: you have to start the database, wait for it to be ready, make your query, and then shut down the database.

However, you don't have to make the query specifically from inside the database container.  It looks like you already have a block in the `docker-compose.yml` file to start the database, so you can

```sh
# Start the database
docker-compose up -d db

# Try to connect to the database
mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -e 'SELECT 1;'
# Repeat until successful, usually 30-60 seconds

# Make your actual query
mysql -h 127.0.0.1 my-db-name -e "SELECT *"

# Stop the database
docker-compose down db
```

This is exactly what you'd need to do if the database wasn't in Docker as well (replace `docker-compose` commands with `/etc/init.d/mysql` commands).  Docker doesn't make this easier or harder, just different.